# Visual Basic Case Select returning last value regardless of data values

Tags: vb.net, select-case

After entering an "A" worthy grade the case select is still returning an "F". I know it's simple but what's wrong here?

```
'perform calculations
totalTest = (testScore1 + testScore2 + testScore3) / 3 * testWeight
totalLab = (labScore1 + labScore2 + labScore3 + labScore4 + labScore5) / 5 * labWeight
totalQuiz = (quizScore1 + quizScore2 + quizScore3 + quizScore4) / 4 * quizWeight
totalFinal = finalScore * finalWeight

totalGrades = totalTest + totalLab + totalQuiz + totalFinal

Select Case grade
    Case 90 To 100
        letterGradeLabel.Text = "A"
    Case 80 To 89.99
        letterGradeLabel.Text = "B"
    Case 70 To 79.99
        letterGradeLabel.Text = "C"
    Case 60 To 69.99
        letterGradeLabel.Text = "D"
    Case Else
        letterGradeLabel.Text = "F"
End Select

'display average and letter grade
finalGradeLabel.Text = totalGrades.ToString
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Select Case totalGrades` instead of `Select Case grade`?

Comment: Thanks! Of course it should be.  Knew it was right under my nose

Comment: FWIW, you would catch this much sooner if you had used `Option Explicit` to block implicit declaration of variables. I highly encourage using it to help avoid those kind of errors.

Comment: I don't know the values of your weights, but if a student comes up with a total grade of 89.995 they are going to be unhappy with their grade. There is no reason not to use 80 to 90 for B, as the 90 for A will catch it first, and anything slightly less will be in B and not fall through to F. Also if rounding allows a total grade higher than 100, you'd get an F.

Comment: Alternatively, use `Case Is >= 90` for A, `Case Is >= 80` for B, and so on.